# Setting variable bar widths in R barplot

Tags: r, width, bar-chart

I would like to be able to vary bar widths for a barplot with a continuous variable plotted against two factors. Not all the factor combinations have values in them and I would like them to either not be plotted or have a much smaller bar width. This is to avoid wasting space in the figure. [This is the kind of chart I am making](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcT9F.jpg) It has points superimposed over transparent bars.

I have used base R for a series of barplots and would rather not turn to ggplot2 if possible.

I have tried varying "width" and "space" but cannot get this to work. The width vector gets recycled after the first two terms.

Example code

```
mydata=data.frame(y=rnorm(50,1,1))

group1=c(rep(1, times=30), rep(rep(c(1,2), each = 5), times=2))

group2=rep(c(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")), each=10)

cbind(mydata, group1, group2)


xbar=with(mydata, tapply(y, list(group1, group2), mean, na.rm=TRUE))    


barplot(xbar, beside = TRUE)

legend("topleft", legend=c("Group 1", "Group 2"),
       text.col=c("black", "gray50"))
```

Can anyone suggest a way to remove the spaces where there are no bars as there is no data in that factor combination? Many thanks in advance.

[Barplot showing empty space for empty factor combination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf8Kn.jpg)

These are the things I have tried with width
`    width=0.5

```
xlim=c(0,width*11)

w=c(width, 0, width, 0, width, 0, width, width, width, width)  

barplot(xbar, beside=TRUE, width=w, xlim=xlim)`
```

This I think only uses the first two values of the vector.
[Trying to vary width as a vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBGQz.jpg)

I also tried it as a dataframe (even though the documentation asks for a vector) - this gives the same result as the vector attempt above

```
single=c(width, 0)

double=c(width, width)

w=cbind(single, single, single, double, double)

barplot(xbar, beside=TRUE, width=w, xlim=xlim)
```

Comment: `barplot` has a `width` argument; show us what you tried with this argument that didn't work.

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for your reply I have edited my post with what I have tried

Comment: there should be one width for each bar. space is the argument that controls gaps between bars.

Answer (score 1):

You can try in ggplot

```
library(tidyverse)
cbind(mydata, group1, group2) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(group2, y, fill=factor(group1))) + 
    stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun.y = "mean", position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
    stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar",position = position_dodge(0.9)) + 
    geom_point(aes(shape=factor(group1)),position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

[image]

In base R you can try this

```
# data
df <- cbind(mydata, group1, group2)
xbar=with(df, tapply(y, list(group1, group2), mean, na.rm=TRUE))    

# barplot
d <- xbar
d[2,1:3] <- d[1,1:3]
h <- barplot(d, beside=T, col=c(rep("darkgrey",7),"lightgrey","darkgrey","lightgrey"), border = NA, ylim = c(-3,3))

# get x positions
xpos <- h[2,]-diff(h)/2
xpos[4:5] <- h[,4]
xpos <- c(xpos, h[,5])
xpos
[1]  2.0  5.0  8.0 10.5 11.5 13.5 14.5

# add points
df$xpos <- NA
df$xpos[df$group2 == "A"] <- xpos[1]
df$xpos[df$group2 == "B"] <- xpos[2]
df$xpos[df$group2 == "C"] <- xpos[3]
df$xpos[df$group2 == "D" & df$group1 == 1 ] <- xpos[4]
df$xpos[df$group2 == "D" & df$group1 == 2 ] <- xpos[5]
df$xpos[df$group2 == "E" & df$group1 == 1 ] <- xpos[6]
df$xpos[df$group2 == "E" & df$group1 == 2 ] <- xpos[7]

points(df$xpos, df$y, pch=df$group1)

# add sd bars 
xsd=with(mydata, tapply(y, list(group1, group2), sd, na.rm=TRUE))   
xsd <- c(xsd[1,], xsd[2,4:5])
xsd <- xsd[order(names(xsd))]

arrows(x0 = xpos, x1 = xpos, y0 = c(xbar)[!is.na(c(xbar))]-xsd, y1 = c(xbar)[!is.na(c(xbar))]+xsd,angle=90,code=3,length=0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Jimbou. It does seem like I should have started with ggplot initially as it can address my need but I am so close to finishing everything in base R I would like to persevere. I like your clever way of plotting the bars in base R. Unfortunately it won't work for my scenario as I am also superimposing points representing individual data points. I perhaps oversimplified my example code and have edited my post with some example output closer to what I need.

Comment: @Katie no idea what you mean. please show an example including the bars and the points. Then I can help you.

Comment: in addition I think it is not possible to define more than two widths as the length of the width is defined in the function as `NR <- nrow(height)`. Thus you can only set e.g. `c(.5,.5)`. See `barplot.default`

Comment: Hi Jimbou, I think you are right about the width definitions being limited to two. I  added a link to an example with bar and points to my question in the first paragraph. Apologies I don't see a way to add images to this comment. I have been a longtime reader but am new to posting here!